# Retrieve device information in Linux from device file descriptor using c++

Tags: c++, linux

How i can get device info including the device name from the device file descriptor?

For example, in SKYPE i can see that device "/dev/snd/pcmC2D0c" has name: "USB 2.0 Camera. USB Audio Default Audio Device (default:CARD=Camera)"

How i can get such device name using c++?

```
int file = open("/dev/snd/pcmC2D0c", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0);
if (-1 == file) // check is error occurred during opening?
{
    perror("open");
    return -1;
}
if (-1 == ioctl(file, /* appropriate ioctl value to get the device info? */, /* appropriate structure to fill with device info? */))
{
    perror("ioctl");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You can use [`fstat(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) to get the device ID of the device, but that's probably not very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no `ioctl` values for getting device information. In this special case it's a USB device, which has other sources for device type information.

You can look into the `sysfs` file system, mounted at `/sys`. There is a directory `/sys/bus/usb/devices/`, which has symbolic link entries pointing to the real devices.

On my system, there is for example `/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4`. This symbolic link leads to the directory `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-4/`, which has several files identifying the device.

`idVendor` and `idProduct` contain the numbers `045e` and `00cb`. With these numbers, you can look into the file `/usr/share/misc/usb.ids` and will find

```
...
045e  Microsoft Corp.
...
        00ca  Fingerprint Reader
        00cb  Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
        00ce  Generic PPC Flash device
...
```

You have similar information for hard disk drives, for example. `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/` is my hard disk and the entry `device/model` in this directory contains the string `TOSHIBA DT01ACA1`, identifying it as a THOSHIBA 1TB hard disk drive.

Answer (score 1):

The device info is not retrieved by some ioctl (though by chaining a lot of ioctls you could do this), but through sysfs and/or udev. You can use the command line tool `/sbin/udevadm` to query info about devices. Effectively udev will do an attribute walk through sysfs and query all the information from there. But for convenience this is abstracted by udev.

Try out the following on an arbitrary entry in /dev

```
/sbin/udevadm info --query all --name=/dev/...
```

There's an equivalent to this in the udev API http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/libudev/