# c++ Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: c++, linux, usb

I'm using a USB device usually connected on /dev/ttyUSB0

Sometimes when there's more USB devices it goes to /dev/ttyUSB1 or others

I've added a rule under /etc/udev/rules.d/myrule.rules with the following line:

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="xxxx", ATTRS{idProduct}=="yyyy",
>   MODE="0666", SYMLINK="MyUSB"

That works fine, when I plug my USB device I get the /dev/MyUSB file ready.

The problem is that when I try to access to this file using my C++ program it doesn't work sending a message: "Inappropriate ioctl for device".
If I use the /dev/ttyUSB0, which is also available everything works well.

Do I have to modify my C++ code to deal with SYMLINKS ?

Thanks in advance,

Carles.

Comment: I think you may find your answer here (Retrieve device information from file descriptor): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070737/retrieve-device-information-in-linux-from-device-file-descriptor-using-c You can get the device from a file descriptor using fstat

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. I tested it using a flash drive

Add the rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/myrule.rules
Reload the rules using sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
In the program

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {    
  struct stat buf;
  int fd = open("/dev/MyUSB", O_RDWR  | O_CREAT);
  int k = fstat(fd, &buf);

  // The device handle is contained in st_rdev
  dev_t dt = buf.st_rdev;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, what you post makes sense and that's what my code looked like. But it doesn't work... it always give me the same message "Inappropriate ioctl for device".

Comment: It is really strange, I tested it using a standard flash drive. What kind of device are you using - have you tried running it as root. Perhaps your toolchain is broken.

Comment: The device is a motor board controller. What do you mean by my tookchain is broken?

Comment: I have been using the GNU toolchain for cross-compiling for e.g. ARM and in some case I have used drivers or headers, which were incompatible with the running kernel. I suggest you try the above using a standard USB flash disk - if this gives the same error, this will reveal a broken toolchain